# Usage of "to be done"

Tags: grammar, infinitives, speech

The following is a transcript of the well-known [recorded lecture by Prof. Michael Sandel of Harvard University](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqzW0eHzDSQ&t=43m36s) (the cited portion starts at 43:36):

> The only argument this painter makes is that **the work was necessary to be done**. But this is no good answer, because by the same rule, **this painter may** go through every house in Edinburgh and **do what he thinks proper to be done without the landlord's consent**, and give the same reason that the work was necessary and that house was the better for it.

For easy reference, I'll number the sentences as follows:

> 1. "The work was necessary to be done."
> 2. "This painter may do what he thinks proper to be done without the landlord's consent."

Here're my questions:

Is (1) ungrammatical, grammatical but awkward, or natural?

How about (2)?

If you find (1) or (2) awkward or ungrammatical, how would you rewrite them?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I wouldn't say them quite that way, but I have no objection to either of them. And I will not suggest rewrites because this is a highly specialized field in which the phrases *necessary to be done* and *proper to be done* may be "terms of art", technical terms in law, or terms quoted from a pleading or a governing statute or judicial ruling. Accordingly, and for that reason only, I am going to recommend this question be closed as Too Localized; but I will not be unhappy if that recommendation is bypassed.

Comment: @StoneyB: I believe you are mistaken. This is not about art or law: it is from a lecture on moral philosophy. There is no technical or other jargon here. This is a fine question.

Comment: Google Ngrams shows that _necessary to be done_ was significantly more popular in 1800 than in 2000, when it seemed to fall to almost zero usage.

Comment: @StoneyB/Cerberus I agree with Cerberus that this cannot be a technical jargon or some such. The reason is because the lecture is "the first Harvard course to be made freely available online and on public television." [link](http://www.justiceharvard.org/about/course/)

Comment: @Cerberus  I agree that it's a good question; but the passage in question is a quotation, a legal [pleading](http://books.google.com/books?id=7HXJAqqNl4QC&pg=PA564&lpg=PA564&dq=%22work+was+necessary+to+be+done%22&source=bl&ots=v-PNMOshIQ&sig=ME5hcol2rNNjQNUcuwFx8XAs3Gk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Bi-FUIKVB8SVyQHLvoD4Aw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22work%20was%20necessary%20to%20be%20done%22&f=false) written by Hume acting as his own lawyer.

Comment: @Cerberus Also, Google gives 37 hits on "work was necessary to be done". Of these, 9 are this quote; 22 appear in legal, regulatory or legislative contexts. The corresponding numbers in Google Books are 2 and 13 of 16 identifiable. This is a strong indication that it is a fixed phrase employed because it has an established legal meaning.

Comment: @StoneyB: What I mean is, a question should only be closed if the genre of the text it is from is such that an answer would mainly be about the technicalities of a field that has nothing to do with English. This is no such text. The phrase itself may be normally used in legal or older texts, but that is no problem: that is exactly what the answer should explain.

Comment: @StoneyB: If your flimsy statistics are any indication, the vast majority of lawyers has NEVER been using "to be done" in such contexts. If indeed it were to have an established legal meaning, you could have found at least hundreds or even thousands of hits, but you only ended up finding only "22" hits. Moreover, I can hardly fathom how the seemingly redundant "to be done" would be even remotely considered legalese, unless legalese is only there to confuse laypeople.

Comment: @user27275  I used a very long phrase to limit the hits to a number I could review to eliminate garbage. "Necessary to be done" was in Hume's day a fixed idiom dating back to at least 1588 and still in everyday use in the US Civil War. It was used in laws as early as 1623. I haven't room to paste links here; but if you Google "necessary to be done" you will find your thousands, including uses by Hobbes, Locke, Paine, Hamilton, Madison and Jefferson, as well as legal precedents and 21st century boilerplate respecting trusts and powers of attorney. You'll find even more at Google Books.

Comment: @StoneyB: After some further research on Google, I've come to realize that you have been right all along. And kudos to you for helping me understand the whole thing. The irony is, though, my understanding of the phrases would not have been this clear had I not known of their origin.

Answer (score 3):

Such usage is not unprecedented. The Oxford English Dictionary has at least two citations which include *necessary to be done*. It might be objected that they are from the eighteenth century, but the OED itself, in its definition 33a for *do*, uses *proper or necessary to be done*. Moreover, the Corpus of Contemporary American English has four citations for *necessary to be done* and the British National Corpus, one.

Whether or not the sentences are grammatical, they are not particularly elegant or effective. Alternatives for the first might be:

> The only argument this painter makes is that the work was necessary.
>
> The only argument this painter makes is that the work needed to be
> done.

Alternatives for the second might be:

> . . . this painter may go through every house in Edinburgh and do what
> he thinks proper without the landlord's consent . . .
>
> . . . this painter may go through every house in Edinburgh and do what he thinks
> it is proper to do without the landlord's consent . . .

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is not grammatical. *(Be) necessary* is not a predicate that allows A-Raising, which is what would raise the subject of *be done* to  the position of subject of *be necessary*.

It's not the work that's necessary; it's someone doing the work. I.e, *the work* starts off as the object of *do*, gets passivized to the subject of *be done*. The derivation starts off as

- *(For `INDEF`) to do the work is necessary.* ====>
- *(For) the work to be done is necessary.*

So far so good. But this is an awkward sentence with a heavy clausal subject, and normally it would be extraposed, viz

- *It is necessary for the work to be done.*

However, the writer attempted instead to perform [A-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), which is a governed rule (i.e, whether it can be applied or not depends on what the main predicate is), and *necessary* is a predicate that does not govern Raising. Other predicates do, but not *necessary* (or *possible*).

- *The work turned out to be done.*
- *The work happened to be done.*
- *The work is likely to be done.*

but

- **The work is possible to be done.*
- **The work is necessary to be done.*

As for the second sentence, *think* does govern B-Raising, so

- *what he thinks (to be) proper*

is fine, if one stops there. But the author added *to be done* after it, and *(be) proper* does not govern A-Raising. Hence it's not grammatical either.

Finally, there is no reason I can see why *do the work* has to be passivized in the first place; it adds nothing except syntactic complexity, and has tempted the author to indulge here in unsupportable syntactic flights of formality. If this was submitted in a paper in my class, I'd require it to be rewritten (NB: *require* governs Raising, too).

Comment: But this is not a contemporary use; it's a legal document from 1774, employing the idiom "necessary to be done" (often "fit and necessary to be done") used in legal and political contexts since 1588 and still in use in those contexts today.

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that. 200+ years ago English syntax was different; very different. The language is still innovating syntactic constructions to replace its lost morphology and they change at a furious rate (furious for languages, anyway).

Comment: Exactly. *Need* was not yet a common semi-modal. And then  legal language is for obvious reasons very slow to change.