# Is "If you be..." correct?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conditionals

Are the "If you be my everything..." and "If I be wrong" structures correct?
Thank you for the answers!

Comment: 'Correct' as in 'can be found in extremely large and probably dated books on grammar' or 'correct' as in 'people won't think you've swallowed an extremely large and probably dated book on grammar'?

Comment: And [another question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89983/under-what-circumstances-can-the-word-be-be-used-directly-without-any-change) (with its [nominated duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/when-should-i-use-the-subjunctive-mood)).

Comment: Generally correct, but archaic.  Probably should only be used for the poetic effect, if at all.

Comment: What was current in the 18th century may today be understood only as pirate speech.